# How can I blur a div where contentEditable=true?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

How can I blur/focusout a div where *contentEditable=true*? I have attempted `$(elm).blur()` and `$(elm).attr('contentEditable', false);`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`$("div[contentEditable]").blur()` to blur all contentEditable elements.

`$("#elementId").blur()` to blur an element by its `id`.

Comment: I think, technically, it should be *$('div[contentEditable="true"]').blur()*

Comment: `div[contentEditable]` checks for the presence of the contentEditable attribute, `div[contentEditable="true"]` checks if that attribute is set to true. Either will work in most cases. You would only have to be explicit if you explicitly set contentEditable to some other value to disable it.

Comment: `div[contentEditable!="false"]` would probably be your best choice for simplicity.

Comment: It would be nice if you could mark Marek Suscak's answer as a solution, since this one does not resolve the issue. Thanks in advance!

Comment: is not enough to blur() the element, you should unselect-it, otherwise the element even if is not focused will be receiving user input (check marek-suscak answer)

Answer (score 38):

I would add another solution that is based on Omnicon's answer which is correct BTW. I have [forked his fiddle and updated it](http://jsfiddle.net/mareksuscak/oytdoxy8/).

The trick is to remove all ranges after calling blur:

```
$(".editable").blur();
window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
```

Comment: This worked for me, thanks. Omnicon's did not work for me, partly because it scrolled the whole document to the bottom when invoked.

Comment: The removeAllRanges() works really well, previously I use ony the $(".editable").blur(); and the contentEditable element still wouldn't get rid of the selection. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the solution! `window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();` does the trick - without it editable div is still active and next `e.codeKey == 13` returns in adding a new line.

Comment: This is helped when using contenteditable with draggable and ckeditor.

Answer (score 3):

The suggested solution by Roman Resh doesn't work when you click into the element and hit enter immediately after. It won't blur but create line-breaks/divs.

It is possible to prevent this behaviour entirely.

[See this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kwc6mvcp/)

`$('<div class="temp-contenteditable-el" contenteditable="true"></div>')
.appendTo('body').focus().remove();`

Answer (score 0):

Appending to all answers, when using something like

```
$(".editable").blur()
```

think about blurring only focused, like

```
$(".editable:focus").blur()
```

If not you can get into nice probs sometimes