# Ionic hide cursor

Tags: ionic-framework

When my content editable `<div>` (chat field) gets blurred, the keyboard closes but the (blue) cursor remains visible.

Is there a way to hide the cursor?

```
<div class="chat-message" contenteditable="true" data-ph="Typ een bericht..."></div>
```

[image: After blurring]

Comment: This is not directly related to ionic but pure html. There are different ways to solve this here  http://stackoverflow.com/q/3671141/4515566

Comment: @arainone That topic is about carets, not about cursors. I ment the blue icon.

Comment: ha ok.. but isn't this blue cursor your phone native cursor? If that is the case, i don't know about any pure javascript solution to this problem, you would have to mess with native code... or use a ionic/cordova plugin it that exists.

Comment: Im afraid it is. I will take a look, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching some more I stumbled on the following topic: [How can I blur a div where contentEditable=true?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4878713/how-can-i-blur-a-div-where-contenteditable-true)

It seems that content editable works a bit different than normal textareas.
You have to clear the selection, which actually sounds really obvious when you think about it..

So what works for me is the following:

```
 $('#chat .chat-footer .chat-actions .chat-message').on('blur', function () {
        window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
    });
```